# Big-O Notation: What is the order of the algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I'm having trouble understanding Big-O Notation. Here is an algorithm I wrote, it is supposed to be an alternative of (C++) Stack's size() function, and I need to determine its running time with the assumption that there are *n* elements in the stack when it is invoked.

```
Algorithm size():
    Input: none
    Output: A constant value of the size of an n-element stack.
Let V be a vector of n type objects.
Let S be the name of the stack that is being operated on by this function.
K ← 0                       
V
while !empty() 
    V.push_back(top())      //Keep track of elements in V
    S.pop()             //Remove element from stack
    K ← K + 1           //Count the size of the stack
return K                //Return the size of the stack  
for i ← K – 1, i > 0, i-- do            
    S.push(V[i])            //Retain initial contents of stack
```

Please correct me where I'm wrong:

- In the line K ← 0, I think that is an O(1) operation.
- Creating the vector V is also an O(1) operation.
- the while loop is an O(n) operation since it runs until it empties a stack containing *n* contents.
- Pushing values back into V is an O(n) operation.
- Popping contents off the stack S is an O(n) operation.
- Returning K is an O(1) operation.
- The for loop is an O(n) operation.
- Pushing contents back into S is an O(n) operation.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions about Big-Oh notation.

Comment: Unless you have to copy the entire vector or stack, pushing and popping elements should be O(1).

Comment: The `for` loop will never be executed, because it's after the `return` statement.

Comment: Looks to me like you have the algorithm a bit wrong, but the individual complexities pretty much correct. Usually you'd summarize the overall complexity as the "worst" of the component complexities, O(n) in your case.

Comment: @JerryCoffin besides the return statement thing that Barmar pointed out, what is wrong about the algorithm?

Comment: I'd have to write/run code to be *sure* but I believe you also have an off-by-one error on copying the data back from V to S (you go from k-1 down to 1, but should go from K-1 down to 0).

Comment: Shall we assume the unbound `empty()` and `top()` are actually from `S` ?

Comment: *"The for loop is an O(n) operation. Pushing contents back into S is an O(n) operation."* - this is imprecise.  The loop iterates O(n) times invoking the single-element push with is O(1) each time it runs.  Collectively, the whole loop & push thing is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

The push and pop operations are O(1). The for loop that contains the push is O(n) and the push is O(1).

MIT Always puts out good stuff to study http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf.